# Start processing file as soon as it is streamed in Jersey Mulipart upload

Tags: jersey, streaming, jax-rs, multipartform-data

I have a JAX-RS web service which implements a multipart file upload request.
The web service needs to compress the file and store it. This takes a lot of time.
This processing begins only after the entire file is uploaded from the client.

I would like to start processing the InputStream of the file as and when the file becomes available on the server.

My JAX-RS code:

```java
   /**
     * POST method for uploading a file
     * @param content representation for the resource
     * @return an HTTP response with content of the updated or created resource.
     */
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String uploadPhoto (
            @FormDataParam("file") final InputStream uploadedInputStream,
            @FormDataParam("file") final FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail,         
            @FormDataParam("key") final String key,
            @FormDataParam("userid") final int userId)  throws Exception {

        String imgURL = **FileProcessor.process**(uploadedInputStream);
        return buildUploadResponse(url);

    }
```

This is a screenshot of the how the request timing on chrome

[image]

In the image above, you can see there are two time periods "RequestTime" "Waiting Time"  The "FileProcess.process" is run only during the waiting time.Why can't it execute as soon as the file stream becomes available?